# How can I fix the date formats which have gone wrong in 18.04 when setting first day of the week?

Tags: upgrade

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu Studio 16.04 to 18.04. Some things got reset and need changing back to how I want.

I want the calendar to start on Sunday, and managed to get that done by editing en_GB locale file, making first weekday = 1.

But, now in all other programs, the date formats are in US format, e.g. May 03, 2019; but I want them back to the UK format of 3 May 2019.

Despite the en_GB locale file seeming to have all the right settings, I am now stuck with dates in US format, which is hard to read, e.g. 05/03/19 -- is that 5th of March or 3rd of May?

So how can I get it have Sunday as first day of week, and all date formats in UK format (as it all was back in 16.04)?

Comment: I can't help with your issue sorry, but did you enable the PPA to get continued support for Ubuntu Studio 18.04 (which was not a LTS release), see https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/

Comment: Please list the contents of ~/etc/default/locale

Comment: Yes, I added the PPA

Comment: I am also finding that all my desktop icons have vanished, and I cannot right-click on the desktop.

Comment: The file ~/etc/default/locale is currently empty

Comment: I managed to fix it.

After doing  locale | grep LC_TIME

it showed the answer
LC_TIME=C.UTF-8

previously it had been

LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8

In the C locale file, it had US settings, so I copied en_GB over it, and after doing sudo locale-gen and logging out and logging in again, it was all back to how it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it.

After doing  locale | grep LC_TIME

it showed the answer
LC_TIME=C.UTF-8

previously it had been

LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8

In the C locale file, it had US settings, so I copied en_GB over it, and after doing sudo locale-gen and logging out and logging in again, it was all back to how it should be.